# why am I not able to print the html address and title from a html page source?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing

I am trying to get an article link and title of that article from an HTML data of a page, I tried using this code

```
def get_ndtvsports_articles():

    cricbuzz_article_link = "https://sports.ndtv.com/cricket"

    r = requests.get(ndtvsports_article_link)
    ndtvsports_article_html = r.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(ndtvsports_article_html, "html.parser")
    # print(soup.prettify())

    ndtvsports_items = soup.find_all("div",
                                     {"class": "post-title"})

    ndtvsports_article_dict = {}

    for div in ndtvsports_items:
        ndtvsports_article_dict[div.find('a')['title']] = div.find('a')['href']

    return ndtvsports_article_dict
```

I ended up getting output as this

```
<function get_ndtvsports_articles at 0x7f33fb762950>
This does not have a text entry
This does not have a text entry
This does not have a text entry
This does not have a text entry
This does not have a text entry
This does not have a text entry
```

I was expecting to get href link and page title like this

```
{'Mendis misses out on maiden double ton': 'http://www.cricbuzz.com/cricket-news/100130/bangladesh-vs-sri-lanka-1st-test-day-3-tea-kusal-mendis-dananjaya-de-silva-report'}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you are doing is

```
print(get_ndtvsports_articles)
```

and NOT

```
print(get_ndtvsports_articles())
```

Comment: now why am I getting     ndtvsports_article_dict[div.find('a')['title']] = div.find('a')['href']

    TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable?

Comment: When you do `div.find('a')` the result is that there are zero of them, then when you go to take the `['href']` subscript (or maybe the `['title']`) it's trying to index `None` and getting confused.

Comment: why am I getting div.find('a') as Zero, did I call it wrong?

Comment: @NikhilRaghunath is it guaranteed that every post title will have a link in it and every link will have a `['title']` attribute?